# MS Access Query Select Numbers after a period in a query

Tags: ms-access

I know this is simple, however, I cannot find the solution and there are so many SQL examples. I want a simple query builder solution.

Currently trying

`NameofNewField:Left([PullingBaseDataField],-2)`

-2 doesn't work. Data is simple - example below.
S.0001
S.0002

Comment: Try `MID([PullingBaseDataField],  InStr(1, [PullingBaseDataField] ,".")+1, LEN([PullingBaseDataField]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistency in data structure is critical when manipulating strings.

If there will always be "S." followed by digits:

`Replace([PullingBaseDataField], "S.", "")`

Or

`Mid([PullingBaseDataField], 3)`

Otherwise, if there can be more alpha but always a period:
`MID([PullingBaseDataField],  InStr([PullingBaseDataField], ".") + 1)`

Comment: This works and is now a great refence for other fields that I needed.